# Why must number "b" be a factor of 24 in case P(b)=O where P(x) is some quadrinomial ( of degree 3) with a final constant term equal to 24?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, soft-question

Reference : https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/default/upfiles/AlgebraReview.pdf, page 5.

In James Stewart's *Review Of Algebra* (a chapter of one of his *Calculus* Books I believe), I read this:

> Let $P(x)= x^3 - 3x^2 - 10x + 24$, and $P(b)= 0$; then $b$ must be a factor of 24.

This is preliminary work to apply the factor theorem ( for polynomials of degree 3 or more).

Could you please explain on which ground Stewart asserts that " b must be a factor of 24".

Is there some other theorem involved here, of which I would have no knowledge?

Comment: See the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Comment: @fleablood:  after I saw the other answer, I checked the reference link, and it does state that $b$ is an integer

Comment: Yeah, I did too.  I probably should have checked before I posted.  Then again its an important distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), if $b$ is rational and $P(b)=b^3-3b^2-10b+24=0$,

then $b$ is a factor of $24$.

Comment: Does the rational root theorem imply " b factor of 24" in the following way? b=b/1, so , if b is a solution, b/1 is a rational solution, therefore the numerator of b/1  divides 24, and finally, b divides 24?

Comment: The numerator of $b$ in lowest terms divides $24$, and the denominator divides $1$ (so it's $1$)

Comment: But the text hasn't proven or stated the rational root theorem yet....

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion rather than searching for theorems, it's better to prove it yourself.

$P(b) = b^3 - 3b^2 - 10b +24 =0$

Or, $b(3b + 10 - b^2) = 24$.

From this equation, it's clear that $b$ is a factor of $24$. Hence it's simple.

Comment: @RayLittleRock: I thought there was a typo too, at first. But it's just Abhirup's eccentric style: $3b+10-b^2$ is middle-endian, like the US date format mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: This is a very elegant answer!

Comment: Apparently it works for every polynomial of degree 3. Do you know whether this factoring out technique also works for more than degree 3 polynomials?

Comment: $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+.... + a_1 x + C$.  Then if $P(b)=0$ then $ a_nb^n + a_{n-1} b^{n-1}+.... + a_1b + C$ and $-(a_nb^n + a_{n-1} b^{n-1}+.... + a_1b) = -b(a_nb^{n-1} + a_{n-1} b^{n-2}+.... + a_1) = C$ so yes, this is always true.  (I think the text assumed this was obvious).